# Principle of getting new letters from my Google Account on device

Tags: java, android

I need information about getting new letters from my gmail mailbox: i turn on synchronization on my device, and when my mailbox get a new letter gmail client on my device will respond to it and show me notification. How does it work? Gmail client sends requests every second/minute or there is mean to respond to this event? I need it, because i have been making application which must respond to a new event in Google Calendar. Thank you.

Comment: There is pull email, where your device/software periodically asks the server. If you use the gmail client in Android, it's doing [push email](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_email)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-google-tasks-api-and-oauth-20-on.html).
Might be helpful, I was trying something similar....